# Real analysis - Problem on Continuity

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, metric-spaces

Is it possible to have a function on a metric space which is discontinuous at every point of the metric
space but the restriction of that function on a dense set is continuous?

Answer (score 3):

Yes $f: \Bbb R \to  \Bbb R$ defined by: $$f(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & x \in \Bbb Q\\
                            0 & x \notin \Bbb Q\\
\end{cases}$$

is everywhere discontinuous but constant (so continuous) on both dense sets $\Bbb Q$ and $\Bbb R\setminus \Bbb Q$.